# When does $|z_1+z_2|^2 \leq |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$ hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers, show with proof when does

$|z_1+z_2|^2 \leq |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$ hold?

I guess that I can use $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$ with a triangle inequality

Comment: What happens if you substitute the identity you mentioned? Feel free to provide your ansatz & calculations, this will motivate people to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

If $z = x + yi$, where $x$ and $y$ are real, then I assume the absolute value signs means the standard modulus, such as defined in the [Complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) section of Wikipedia's "Absolute values" article, i.e.,

$$|z|^2 = x^2 + y^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, in that case, your statement is not always true. For example, have

$$z_1 = 2 + i \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
$$z_2 = 1 + 2i \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Then

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
|z_1 + z_2|^2 & = |(2 + i) + (1 + 2i)|^2 \\
& = |3 + 3i|^2 \\
& = 9 + 9 \\
& = 18
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

but

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 & = |2 + i|^2 + |1 + 2i|^2 \\
& = (4 + 1) + (1 + 4) \\
& = 10
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

As you can see, your statement of

$$|z_1+z_2|^2 \leq |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

is not true in this situation.

If you are using a different meaning for the absolute value signs, please specify what it is.

Comment: One may see my answer posted below.This results does not hold always, it holds only when $\Re(z_1 \bar z_2) \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is incorrect,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\arg{-\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}}\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]&\iff \left|z_{1}+z_{2}\right|^{2}\leq|z_{1}|^{2}+|z_{2}|^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Maybe You mean

$$
\left|\frac{z_{1}+z_{2}}{2}\right|^{2}\leq\frac{|z_{1}|^{2}+|z_{2}|^{2}}{2}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is wrong.

Comment: @Sanghwa Lee I have corrected(edited) your question and given correct answer. You may up-vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is false even for $z_1=z_2\ne 0$

$4|z_1|^2\le 2|z_1|^2$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$|z_1+z_2|^2=(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1+ \bar z_2)=z_1\bar z_1+\bar z_1 z_2+z_1 \bar z_2+ z_2 \bar z_2)= |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+2 \Re (z_1 \bar z_2)$$
$$\implies |z_1+z_2|^2-|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=2 \Re (z_1 \bar z_2)$$
Finally, iff $\Re (z_1 \bar z_2) \le 0$, then only we can have
$$|z_1+z_2|^2\le |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2, ~~if~~\Re (z_1 \bar z_2) \le 0$ $$

For example: $z_1=3-4i, z_2=3-5i$, then LHS is 185 and RHS is 99, becaues $\Re(z_1 \bar z_2)= +43.$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the problem is wrong.